# Databse design for a part/subassembly list

Tags: database-design, ms-access

We work with tracking the fabrication of large assemblies and sub-assemblies with a large flat Excel files. Usually separate spreadsheets for estimating material costs, fabrication costs, keeping track of submittals etc.

I've done some basic work in MS-Access over the years-enough to know there's probably a better way to manage this data--and have thought of developing a tool in Access.  The few times I've sat down to diagram out what the different tables would look like and how they would relate I get stumped by how to treat parts and subbassemblies.  To borrow the diagram from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138928/recursive-cte-to-find-total-for-all-children) question. The data could look like this:

```
Assembly (id:1)
    |
    |-Part 1: Rivet
    |-Part 2: Rivet
    |-Group 1: SubAssembly
    |   |
    |   |-Part 1: Rivet
    |   |-Part 2: Bolt
    |   |-Part 3: Bolt
    |   |-Group 1: SubSubAssembly
    |      |
    |      |-Rivet
    |      |-Rivet
    |
    |-Group 2: SubAssembly
       |-Rivet
       |-Bolt
```

There could be parts or subassemblies (a collection of parts or more assemblies) at each level.  Practicalities aside, there's no limit to the number of levels.

The best I could think of (that doesn't involve hard coding some set max number of levels) is to have a flat table with a field listing the next higher level and somehow sort and organize on that.  That is similar to what appears on the drawing-a box labeled "Next higher level" that may contain another drawing number.  That seems to be counter to the point of using a relational database though.  I'm not looking to develop a central repository of all data, just a desktop tool that I can use to manage my data and if it proves to be useful, share with my co-workers.

What is the proper way to organize this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce this structure, you need an `Assembly` table referencing itself through a `ParentAssemblyID` and a `Part` table. The diagram in Access looks like this:

[image: DB Diagram]

Note that the assembly table appears twice in this diagram. But there's really only one unique table named `Assembly` in the DB.

`AssemblyID` and `PartID` must be declared as primary key (PK). Its easiest to declare them as `AutoNumber` column.

In the Realtionships diagram, insert the `Assembly` table twice, so that you can draw a relation between them. Right click the relation lines and check the boxes "Enforce Referential Integrity" and "Cascade Delete Related Records".

Your example data would have to be entered like this

```
Assembly
-----------------------------------------------------
AssemblyID  Assembly                 ParentAssemblyID
----------  -----------------------  ----------------
  1         Main Assembly
  2         Group 1: SubAssembly        1
  3         Group 2: SubAssembly        1
  4         Group 1: SubSubAssembly     2
-----------------------------------------------------
```

```
Part
---------------------------------
PartID  AssemblyID  Part
------  ----------  -------------
  1       1         Part 1: Rivet
  2       1         Part 2: Rivet
  3       2         Part 1: Rivet
  4       2         Part 2: Bolt
  5       2         Part 3: Bolt
  6       4         Rivet
  7       4         Rivet
  8       3         Rivet
  9       3         Bolt
---------------------------------
```

---

Answer to follow-up question: *"How would I structure it if I wanted the same part to be usable in many assemblies?"*

[image]

Comment: I didn't  know that was possible, thank you!

Comment: Cascaded deletion is a quite dangerous feature. The whole tree can be deleted easily by mistake. I prefer to restrict the deletion by FK so only the leaf nodes can be deleted. And there is a special procedure `DeleteBranch()` that delete leaves recursively up to the given node.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to delete a deeply nested assembly, it's a very tedious task without cascaded deletes. Preventing mistakes by making things tedious is not optimal. A better way would be to mark things to be deleted as deleted or archived together with a delete date. Later, you can clean up older deletes easily.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  I mean that I've used the special stored routine intended solely for branches deleting. User can easily delete the single leaf by `DELETE ...`  but if he want to delete the whole branch he's forced to use `CALL DELBRANCH(id)` routine instead. This routine acts just like the `DELETE` on the unrestricted table.

Comment: Okay. I was assuming that the user does things via an application and does not use SQL or any DB tools.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  How would I structure it if I wanted the same part to be usable in many assemblies?    It seems like tblParts wouldn't have an AssemblyID and tblAssembly would have a field for line item number (an assembly is a collection of line items which could be either a part or another assembly) and then a field to link either a part or an assembly.

Comment: You would have a proper part table not related to assemblies (with part-id PK (not visible to user, autonumber), part name, part-no (visible to user, editable)) and an assembly-part table (with assembly-id PK, FK, part-id PK, FK, optionally quantity).